# Open magnet link without losing focus

Tags: javascript, browser, magnet-uri

Is there a way in javascript (or other) to handle a magnet link without the browser losing the focus? It'd be a little like opening a tab in the background without leaving the current page.

Comment: You could try to do it with an ajax call

Comment: No, you have no control over things external to the browser.

Comment: @ Pataar, that did sound like a good idea but i just get this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load [here is the super long magnet link]. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

Answer (score 5):

I recently had a similar problem, and was able to solve it by creating a named frame on the page and using it as the target for `window.open`:

```
<iframe style="display:none" name="magnetframe"></iframe>

window.open(magnet_uri, 'magnetframe')
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution by using chrome API.

chrome.tabs.update({url: magnet_uri});