# Download multiple torrents from array of magnet links

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I'm trying to use javascript to iterate over an array of "magnet:.." links and download them iteratively.

I am using an iframe to download the link this way:

the HTML code:

```
<button ng-click="downloadSelected()">Get All Selected</button>
.
.
<iframe id='downloader_iframe'></iframe>
```

Inside the controller:

```
function downloadSelected(){
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.magnets.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('downloader_iframe').src = $scope.magnets[i];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the action is happening only for the first link in the array while the rest of them ignored completely.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Make use of `window.open` or `.click` on an `<a>`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) or `.click` on an `<a>`, for example

```
function downloadSelected() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.magnets.length; ++i) {
        window.open($scope.magnets[i], '_blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: it opens as many tabs as the array size is there a way to have only one tab opened or even none ?

Comment: If you use the same name instead of `_blank` it would open just one, but you may find it skips some links the same as with the `<iframe>`. I also tried with a dynamic `<a>` and _Chrome_ wouldn't process the click on it :( Another option would be to use some kind of delay between hitting each page and hope lag is shorter than the timeout?

Comment: Maybe there's a way to send an array of links to the torrents client ? or merge all the links into one ?

Answer (score 1):

I came here but actually found [this solution/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31408095/1275832) more helpful.

Creating a hidden iframe:

```
<iframe style="display:none" name="magnetframe"></iframe>
window.open(magnet_uri, 'magnetframe')
```

Im not sure how this would work with multiple magnet links, maybe if you use multiple iframes? (use 4 iframes and reload another magnet link every 0.5 second per frame so you can process 8 magnet links per second?)

Answer (score 0):

another solution by using chrome API.

`chrome.tabs.update({url: magnet_uri});`

if you want to running at new tab, then add tab id in arguments

`chrome.tabs.create({active: false}, function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: magnet_uri});
});`